# VBA Send Email Notification when User Login Success or Error in UserForm

Tags: vba, excel

```
Option Explicit
Private Trial As Long
Private Sub cmdCheck_Click()
    'Declare the variables
    Dim AddData As Range, Current As Range
    Dim user As Variant, Code As Variant
    Dim PName As Variant, AName As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim TitleStr As String
    Dim msg As VbMsgBoxResult

    'Variables
    user = Me.txtUser.Value
    Code = Me.txtPass.Value
    TitleStr = "Password check"
    result = 0
    Set Current = Sheet2.Range("U8")

    'Error handler`enter code here`
    On Error GoTo errHandler:
    'Destination location for login storage
    Set AddData = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    'Check the login and passcode for the administrator
    If user <> "" And Not IsNumeric(user) And Code <> "" And IsNumeric(Code) Then
        For Each AName In Sheet2.Range("Z8:Z108")
            'If AName = Code Then 'Use this for passcode text
            If AName = CLng(Code) And AName.Offset(0, -1) = user Then ' Use this for passcode numbers only
                MsgBox "Welcome Back: – " & user & " "

                'record user login
                AddData.Value = user
                AddData.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
                'Add usernmae to the worksheet
                Current.Value = user
                'Change variable if the condition is meet
                result = 1
                'Unload the form
                Sheet2.Visible = True
                Sheet2.Select
                Unload Me
                'Show the navigation form
                'frmNavigation.Show
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next AName
    End If

    'Check user login with loop
    If user <> "" And Not IsNumeric(user) And Code <> "" And IsNumeric(Code) Then
    For Each PName In Sheet2.Range("H8:H108")
        'If PName = Code Then 'Use this for passcode text
        If PName = CLng(Code) And PName.Offset(0, -1) = user Then ' Use this for passcode numbers only
            MsgBox "Welcome Back: – " & user & " "
            'record user login
            AddData.Value = user
            AddData.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
            'Add usernmae to the worksheet
            Current.Value = user

            'unhide worksheet for user
            If PName.Offset(0, 1) <> "" Then
                Set ws = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 1).Value)
                ws.Visible = True
            End If


            'show sheet tab if hidden
            ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True

            'Change variable if the condition is meet
            result = 1
            'Unload the form
            Unload Me
            'Show the navigation form
            'frmNavigation.Show
            Exit Sub
            End If
        Next PName
    End If

    'Check to see if an error occurred
    If result = 0 Then
        'Increment error variable
        Trial = Trial + 1
        'Less then 3 error message
        If Trial < 3 Then msg = MsgBox("Wrong password, please try again", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, TitleStr)
        Me.txtUser.SetFocus
        'Last chance and close the workbook
        If Trial = 3 Then
            msg = MsgBox("Wrong password, the form will close…", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, TitleStr)
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub
    'Error block
    errHandler:
    MsgBox "An Error has Occurred " & vbCrLf & "The error number is: " _
    & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
    "Please notify the administrator"
End Sub
```

Can someone help me modify this code to include Email Notification whenever the user successfully or attempted to enter a wrong password in the user form? If we can have the user name and date and time of login access.

I found this code but I don’t know how and where to include it?

```
Private Sub SendMail_Click()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    strbody = "Hi Admin," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Message Line 1" & vbNewLine & _
          "Username:" & vbNewLine & _
          "Password:"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "email address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Message Request"
        .Body = strbody
        .Send

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mielkew

Comment: Do you want us to merge two pieces of codes you seem not to understand?

Comment: K.Davis,

I want to include an email notification to first code whenever a user successfully login or when error attempts is made accessing the file. If this even possible? Yes, I don’t have much knowledge about VBA code and I can’t possibly merge these two codes to suit my needs.

Basically, I just want to be notified by email whenever the files are accessed by the user.

Thanks,
Mielkew

Comment: Then this might not be the right place to look for help as this is not a code writing service. Even if you provide code (copied in your case) you need to show at least a try on your own. BTW If I were you I would not put the logic of the logon into the userform. The userform should just return username and password and then you check. Also it is not good practise to have an Unload in the form itself https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Comment: Yes, I did tried to write on my own but can't make the code work the way I want it. I don't have any idea about VBA just following some tutorial in youtube.